# In what cases would it be useful to put a command within a Java for-loop update statement?

Tags: java, for-loop

I found out yesterday that you can make a Java for-loop that looks like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; System.out.println(j), j++ ) {

/* code */

}
```

This looks really unusual to me. When is coding like this acceptable/useful?

Comment: The fact that you find this unusual is proof enough that it is not acceptable/useful.

Comment: I think it might make sense if you have two variables `i++, j++`

Comment: @PaulBoddington sorry I had my C/C++ hat on. I retracted my comment.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Would that be for debugging purposes?

Comment: @Coffee It depends on the context. As does everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official java documentation says the following about for-loops:

> The general form of the *for* statement can be expressed as follows:

```
for(initialization; termination; increment) {
     statement(s) 
}
```

> When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>
> 1. The *initialization* expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
> 2. When the *termination* expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
> 3. The *increment* expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment
>      or decrement a value.

So while it is possible to have something like `System.out.println(j)` in your *increment* part, it is against the coding conventions according to the official documentation.

The reason why it is allowed to have multiple comma-separated statements in the *increment* part is because you may need to adjust the value of multiple variables during the execution of the *for* loop. So only in this case it is both *acceptable* and *useful* to use this syntactic sugar. The following example illustrates this scenario:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 10; i < 10 && j >= 0; i++, j--) {
   // Statements
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would only ever do something like this if I had two loop variables, eg:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 10; i < 10 && j > 0; i++, j--) {
...
}
```

Apart from that, I would not recommend doing this as it obscures what the for loop is actually doing. It would be better to place any method calls with side effects inside the actual body.

Comment: Or, you could just remove the `j > 0`. But I like the way you think.

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++ ) {
  System.out.println(j);
}
```

I dont see any advantage of using it other than to trick students in the exam. It could be useful to check if student understands the functioning of `for` loop thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

You may also do it this way

```
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; System.out.println(j++)) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible use for the ability to have two operations in the update statement, is that you can manipulate two variables simultaneously. Something like,

```
for (int i = 0, j = 10; i < 10 && j > 0; i++, j--) {
    System.out.printf("i = %d, j = %d%n", i, j);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually gives the code more sense, makes it more readable. It is useful if you have need more than 1 instruction to be executed at the end of each iteration (like incrementing the loop counter). It is generally used to loop through multidimensional arrays.

Comment: IMO it makes code NOT readable